# Automatically Removing Duplicate Files in SoundMiner

Tags: database, soundminer

all!
This may be an extremely basic question but - is it possible to make SoundMiner remove the duplicate files from my library automatically?
I've scanned and found all of my duplicate files, but there are a LOT of them. Is it possible to tell SoundMiner to just go ahead and remove duplicate records or do I literally need to click on each file and hit "remove from database"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Remove from database doesn't delete the file from your hard drive it simply excludes it from its library. I'd recommend Mac Paw Gemini:http://macpaw.com/gemini